# Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.14.8 GB of 6 GB physical memory used

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark job where I do the following

1. Load the data from parquet via spark sql and convert it to a
   pandas df. The datasize is only 250 MB
2. Run an rdd.foreach to
   iterate over a relatively some dataset(1000 rows) and take the
   pandas df from step 1 and do some transformation.

I get a Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits error  after some iterations .

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 14.8 GB of 6 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead
```

**I am unable to understand why the error says 14.8 GB of 6 GB physical memory used ?**

I have tried increasing spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 
I have used the following command

spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 2G --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 --py-files test.zip app_main.py

I am using spark 2.3

```
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 512 MB
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 126 GB
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the common error when memoryOverhead option is used, it is better to use other options to tune jobs.

http://ashkrit.blogspot.com/2018/09/anatomy-of-apache-spark-job.html post talks about this issue and how to deal with it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you infer why the error states that 14.8 GB of 6 GB physical memory used? As I have mentioned 2GB executor memory + 4GB executor memory overhead

Comment: Since you are using it python and spark.python.worker.memory also plays role in total memory allocation